# CORS Prelight Request Locked Up on HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS

Tags: node.js, axios, electron, cors

I have an Electron application that makes requests to an API in its browser window. The application is deployed to around 600 machines, and on a select few I'm having an intermittent issue with preflight requests locking up on `HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS`.

I make the request using Axios with a timeout of 5000ms. The GET request is correctly terminated after 5000ms, but the OPTIONS request seems to stay alive in the background.

There seems to be no pattern to occurrences of this issue. Sometimes 6 consecutive requests will lock up in a row. Other times there can be hours between the locked requests. Once 6 have locked up all other requests to the API lock up as a result of hitting the 6 connection maximum to a single domain.

My assumption is that it's an environmental issue, but I'm not knowledgeable enough in this area to know where to look next.

The netlog of the initial GET request:
[image: GET]

The netlog of the subsequent OPTIONS request:
[image: OPTIONS]